# How to detect command + arrow key in a Swift 3 Cocoa app

Tags: swift, cocoa, keydown

```
override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    switch event.modifierFlags.intersection(.deviceIndependentFlagsMask) {
    case [.command] where event.characters == "9":
        print("command-9")
    case [.command] where event.keyCode == 123:
        print("command-left arrow") // problem: this never executed
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Above is want I have tried. <kbd>command-9</kbd> works like a charm. But <kbd>command - arrow</kbd> doesn't work.

It seems that if you press <kbd>command - arrow</kbd>, the modifier flag is not command. I searched the internet but couldn't get it work.

Answer (score 4):

You could divide your code into two steps and check if <kbd>command</kbd> was clicked first and then `switch` for the `keyCode`:

```
if event.modifierFlags.intersection(.deviceIndependentFlagsMask).contains(.command) {
    switch event.keyCode {
    case 123:
        print("command-left arrow")
    case 124:
        print("command-right arrow")
    case 125:
        print("command-down arrow")
    case 126:
        print("command-up arrow")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

This will print out when <kbd>command - left arrow</kbd> is clicked.

**Update**
To restrict to only <kbd>command + arrow keys</kbd> use this `if-statement`:

```
if event.modifierFlags.intersection(.deviceIndependentFlagsMask).contains(.command) &&
    !event.modifierFlags.intersection(.deviceIndependentFlagsMask).contains(.option) &&
    !event.modifierFlags.intersection(.deviceIndependentFlagsMask).contains(.control) &&
    !event.modifierFlags.intersection(.deviceIndependentFlagsMask).contains(.function) &&
    !event.modifierFlags.intersection(.deviceIndependentFlagsMask).contains(.shift) &&
    !event.modifierFlags.intersection(.deviceIndependentFlagsMask).contains(.capsLock) {

}
```

Comment: It works. I am wondering is there a more readable way to check the modifier  flags than the magic number `11534336` ?

Comment: It's not perfect because it cannot distinguish command-option-arrow and command-arrow.

Comment: @TylerLong, check the update. Now it should be perfect (:

Comment: I am afraid that you also need to write if statements for other modifiers, such as control. I still look forward to an elegant solution.

Comment: There you have more alternatives in the update. If you want more combinations just apply it to the if statement.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Swift but can't you do `event.modifierFlags.intersection(.deviceIndependentFlagsMask) == [.command]` or something like that?

Comment: In Swift it would be: `event.modifierFlags.contains(.command)`

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5 Solution** - *The below code also works on Mac Catalyst*

```
override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    guard let key = presses.first?.key else { return }
    if key.modifierFlags.contains(.command) {
        switch key.keyCode {
        case .keyboardUpArrow:
            print("command + up arrow")
        case .keyboardDownArrow:
            print("command + down arrow")
        case .keyboardLeftArrow:
            print("command + left arrow")
        case .keyboardRightArrow:
            print("command + right arrow")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If one only cares whether the Command key is pressed for a keyboard event, regardless of any other modifiers, the following can be used

```
if event.modifierFlags.contains(.command) {
    ...
    }
```

[from a Swift MacOS app written in Xcode 13.3]

Answer (score -1):

I've found an alternative solution and it requires no code at all!.

Because I am writing an Cocoa app, it's common practice to add menu item for an action.

When creating the menu item, I can simply set its "Key Equivalent".